# Devo evitar a injeção de "%" numa consulta onde uso "LIKE"?

Tags: php, mysql, operador-like

Tenho uma página onde consulto o usuário através do nome. A consulta visa a utilização do `LIKE` para capturar o nome do usuário a partir da primeira letra em diante.

Então eu faço a consulta dessa forma

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE 'Gu%'
```

Estou utilizando o `Laravel 3` para fazer essa consulta, então a consulta fica mais ou menos assim.

```
 $search = trim(Input::get('search'));

 Usuario::where('nome', 'LIKE', "{$search}%")->get();
```

O problema que eu notei é que, se o usuário colocar no campo do formulário o texto `"%gu"`, ao invés de ele pesquisar por `Gustavo`, `Gusmão` e `Gumercindo`, ele também pesquisaria por `Al[gu]sto`, `Aldalberto [Gu]smão`. E não é essa intenção.

Isso acontece porque a pesquisa que faço, geraria os seguintes resultados:

```
Pesquisa: wal  => wal%
Pesquisa: %wal => %wal%
```

Mas e se o usuário realmente quiser pesquisar coisas como `30 %`? Isso seria um problema, por causa do `LIKE` usar o `%` como representação de "qualquer coisa".

- Tirando a questão da funcionalidade, existe também outro problema em permitir que o usuário digite, em pesquisas onde uso `LIKE`, o caractere `%`?
- Com eu poderia resolver isso, em `PHP` ou `MYSQL`, pra minha consulta não ser alterada. E, ao invés disso, se o usuário quiser achar algo que contenha `%`, ele encontre o caractere registrado na tabela? Ou seja, existe alguma maneira de escapar o `%` numa consulta com `LIKE`?

Comment: E se fizeres um replace do `%` por `''` na tua input, não te resolvia o problema? Agora se é a melhor solução não sei. Ou então não deixas que o user prima o carácter %

Comment: @CesarMiguel, mas e se o usuário realmente quiser pesquisar lá no banco algo como "30% de desconto"? O nosso sistema usa muito isso!

Comment: Acho que já entendi, queres que ele pesquise na mesma pelo `%`, não que atribua o valor do % no like, é isso?

Comment: Sim. Tanto a solução de remover, quanto a de escapar são boas. Mas a melhor delas é a de escapar. Melhor de tudo é ter uma solução :)

Comment: depende do caso... no exemplo de consulta de nome de usuário, não precisa de caracteres especiais pois nomes são alfanuméricos, então pase um filtro no nome do usuário antes de montar a query.. no outro caso do "30% de desconto",  é meio estranho alguém buscar isso livremente.. normalmente normaliza-se as tabelas para que o valor 30 não fique misturado com textos..  mas no caso de buscar em textos, basta escapar os caracteres reservados do SQL.. simples assim.. tudo questão de lógica de negócio.

Comment: Voce pode escapar o % em um like.

Comment: @wallaceMaxters Não entendi muito bem a questão, vamos ver se é o que entendi.

Caso o usuário digite `gu` a condição deverá ficar `LIKE 'gu%'`. Caso ele venha digitar `%gu` deverá ficar `LIKE '%gu'` ou digitar `gu%` deverá ficar `LIKE 'gu%'`?

Comment: é gluglgu : http://bit.ly/1MeCdE4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode substituir `%` por `\%`. Aproveitando, também substitua `_` por `\_`:

```
$search = trim(Input::get('search'));
$search = str_replace(['_', '%'], ['\_', '\%'], $search)
```

Comment: O que o `_` faz no `LIKE`?

Comment: Também acabei por não entender. Acaba por não responder ao que o @WallaceMaxters quer

Comment: `_` significa qualquer caracter somente um. @WallaceMaxters

Comment: @CesarMiguel, então é importante sim ele ter colocado o `_`, já que faz parte de algo interno do `LIKE`.

Comment: Tá tudo na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), inclusive como lidar com as próprias barras invertidas (como buscar textos contendo-as.)