# Pra que serve o undescore "_" no LIKE do MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, operador-like

Em uma pergunta anterior a respeito do `LIKE` no `MYSQL`, [Devo evitar a injeção de "%" numa consulta onde uso "LIKE"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87474/devo-evitar-a-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-numa-consulta-onde-uso-like/87487?noredirect=1#comment176407_87487), surgiu uma dúvida a respeito do `_` (undescore) poder ser usado no operador `LIKE`.

Já utilizei muito o `%`, mas esse wilcard `_` eu não conhecia. Para que ele serve no `LIKE`do `Mysql`?

Comment: Antes de me criticar dizendo que eu não pesquisei: pesqusei sim, e não achei nada em português.

Comment: https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=pra+que+serve+o+undescore+no+MSQL&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=J_T6VZOfG8aw8wfRhaL4Dw#safe=active&channel=fs&q=para+que+serve+o+underscore+no+MYSQL

Comment: Maioria dos resultados de buscas são em inglês, não português. Tente pesquisar em inglês ou olhar no próprio manual, lá responde diretamente. Desculpe não responder, estou pelo celular.

Comment: Agora vamos ter uma fonte em português então - a minha pergunta.

Comment: hauhau turn down for what!

Comment: Tive que usar o Google tradutor @DanielOmine. E ele disse _vire para baixo para o que!_

Comment: essa frase é de uma musica e virou um viral. busca no youtube que vc vai entender. hehe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O underline (`_`) serve para comparar qualquer caracter somente uma vez, enquanto a porcentagem (`%`) significa qualquer caracter em qualquer quantidade.

(`_`) é equivalente ao meta caracter (`.`) das expressões regulares e (`%`) ao (`.*`)

[MySQL - like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: Quando você citou isso na outra resposta não tinha entendi. Agora é que eu entendi.

Answer (score 1):

O underscores `_` é para encontrar ocorrências em determinadas posição da string.

Vamos supor que eu venha a querer pesquisar todas as string que comecem com `my`.

`LIKE 'my%'`

Irão me retornar registros como: `mySQL`, `Myan`, `Mylan` e etc.

Vamos partir do exemplo que eu queria pesquisar `my` porém a partir da terceira posição da string.

`LIKE '___my%'`

Irão me retornar registros como `hjjmy`, `yuimy` e em diante.

Também tem outras `pattern matching` para o like como por exemplo: `\_` e até `ESCAPE`.

## Edit

Também para marcar posições de ocorrências.

Como no exemplo:

`SELECT 'David!' LIKE '_____';`

Irá ter output **0** pois eu pesquisei por strings que contém 5 ocorrências, já `David!` contém 6 ocorrências.

Se eu utilizar:

`SELECT 'David!' LIKE '______';`

Irá ter output **1**

Já expressão:

`SELECT 'David32' LIKE '_____\32';`

Irá confrontar se _____\32 é igual David32.

Ou seja, 5 ocorrências para frente mais o número 32 existe?

Irá retornar todos os nome que contém 7 ocorrências e as duas ultimas sejam: **32**

Referências: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html