# Filtrar um campo conforme o formato do texto

Tags: php, mysql

É possível eu filtrar em um determinado campo do mysql a seguinte formatação: (21)2222-2222. Peço a compreensão dos colegas se não fui claro na minha dúvida, pois tive um problema no cadastro do qual a máscara:
`$("#telefone").mask("(99)9999-9999");` estava  `$("#telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");` e isso deu problema aqui.

Comment: Da sim vc quer pegar somente os números que não tem o `9` no inicio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode filtrar os números com like usando o coringa para um caractere `_`.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE telefone like '(__)____-____'
```

**Relacionado:**

[Pra que serve o undescore “_” no LIKE do MYSQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87504/91)

Comment: show... perfeito.. nao conhecia esse tipo de filtro... obrigado ray, funcionou

Comment: não está permitindo dar como resposta correta, só depois de 9 minutos, mas vou voltar pra confirmar ;)

Comment: @Fox.11 o `%` ser para especificar qualquer quantia de caracteres e o `_` somente um, mais em: [Pra que serve o undescore “_” no LIKE do MYSQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87504/91)