# Como escapar o caractere de porcentagem (%) no LIKE?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um sistema onde utilizo o `Laravel` para fazer a consulta no banco de dados. Se trata de um formulário de pesquisa.

Eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
$search = trim(Input::get('search'));

return Empresa::where('nome_fantasia', 'LIKE', $search)->get();
```

O problema é que, como eu utilizo o `LIKE` para fazer a consulta pelo  nome, se o usuário adicionar na pesquisa `%` (sinal de porcentagem), ele trás todos os dados, já que se trata de um caractere especial do `%`.

Como faço para escapar o caractere porcentagem no MYSQL?

**Nota**: Adicionei apenas a tag `php` e `mysql`. O `Laravel` nesse caso é apenas a ferramenta que estou usando, mas a solução pode servir indepentedemente de eu usá-lo ou não.

Comment: O que está errado com minha pergunta? O que pode ser melhorado?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87474/91 :D

Comment: @rray eu já tinha perguntado e esqueci! kkkkk. Duplicada, ué.

Comment: Não sei dizer ... o contexto parece diferente.

Comment: As funções de escape tanto do PDO quanto do mysqli já escapam este tipo de caractere. Não sei como o laravel trabalha com isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você necessita escapá-lo:

Pelos testes que fiz no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38975/4). Por padrão o `\` já é o `ESCAPE`, de tal forma que apenas fazendo:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_table
WHERE nome_fantasia LIKE 'name\%name';
```

Ja resolve o problema, contudo caso queira utilizar [outro caractere como `ESCAPE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38975/5) basta declará-lo :

```
SELECT * FROM tb_table
WHERE nome_fantasia LIKE 'name|%name' ESCAPE '|';
```

Se você quer escapar pelo PHP, você também pode usar a função `addcslashes` para escapar apenas o caractere `%`.

Faça assim:

```
$search = '% meu texto aqui';

$search = addcslashes($search, '%');
```

Isso irá retornar:

```
 '\% meu texto aqui'
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar o caracter entre colchetes ex:

Valor procurado `75%`

```
WHERE MinhaColuna LIKE '75[%]'
```

Funciona na grande maioria dos SGBD`s disponíveis no mercado.

Comment: Para o meu cenário, isto funcionou para mim